# How to join two tables defined in two different bundles?

Tags: symfony-2.3, orocrm

I want to join two tables in order to show the details in datagrid.

> Table 1: student

- primary key : id
- foreign key : class_id

> Table 2: class

- primary key : id

class can have many students. **(one to many relationship)**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm using OroCRM

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **join** part to your **datagrid.yml** configuration. Here is an example in documentation: https://oroinc.com/orocrm/doc/2.6/dev-guide/entities/datagrids#data-source

1. In case if your bundles know about each other your join may be like this (from student side): 
   `join:
        left:
             - { join: student.class, alias: class }`

Considering that you created entities with the correct mappins. More details can be found here -
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

2. If only bundle which holds Class entity should know about students you have to use **join table**. More details is here -
   https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table